# where are the rasters that make up a layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, layers

I used raster calculator to add up 12 rasters made up of 0's and 1's to make a fire frequency map. Then I saved the output as a layer (lyr).

However, I need the raster output.

Did I add it up wrong, save the files wrongly or are they saved some where?

Comment: See http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/creating-output.htm

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.2.2. 
In the suggested reading it states that:
“Algebra expressions are always temporary, but can be saved by calling the save method on the Raster object.” How do I do this if I am not using script.

Answer (score 1):

Note that layer files (.lyr) do not save the underlying dataset. But what should matter is that you know where you sent the output raster--like in the bottom of the illustration seen here: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm Is this similar to the dialog box you're using? What path are you putting for your Output Raster? That should be the path of your data.

Comment: The output layer should be in the folder of the path below. However, it does not seem to be present. I dont seem to be able to change this path it just defaults back.                                                                  Data Type:  File Geodatabase Raster Dataset
Database:  C:\Users\XXX\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb
Raster:fire

Comment: What's with the "Raster:" Are you putting that in your output path in the tool dialog? It should be something like C:\Users\XXX\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\fire

Comment: @I.Stirs, are you seeing a dialog box like the one pictured here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000

Comment: Yes I used a similar dialog box. I think the files are locked.  The output  looks like this. fras_aux_rastercalc17.ILOEKHOLZEL15.6392.3908.sr.lock

Comment: I think the temp file got deleted. Redid it and saved using export and now works fine. Thanks for your suggestions Tom